# If $a,b,c\in R: a+b+c=3,$ find maximum $\min\{a,b,c\}+ \sqrt[3]{abc}-\max\{a,b,c\}..$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a,b,c\in R: a+b+c=3,$ find the maximum $$P=\min\{a,b,c\}+ \sqrt[3]{abc}-\max\{a,b,c\}. $$

Some thoughts.

I think we just need to prove $\sqrt[3]{abc}\le 1,$ which is true by AM-GM for $a,b,c\ge 0.$

I don't know how to prove in the remain case of $a,b,c.$

May be there is some good ideas. Hope to see some helps, thank you.

Comment: BW is a good way.

Answer (score 1):

For $a=b=c=1$ we obtain a value $1$.

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, $a\geq0$ and  we need to prove that:
$$c+\sqrt[3]{abc}-a\leq\frac{a+b+c}{3}$$ or
$$4a+b-2c\geq3\sqrt[3]{abc},$$ which is obvious for $abc<0$ and $abc\geq0,$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are non-negatives.

Let $b\leq0$ and $c\leq0$.

Thus, by AM-GM
$$4a+b-2c=3a+a-b+2(b-c)\geq 2a=$$
$$= a+(-b)+(-c)+a+b+c\geq $$
$$\geq a+(-b)+(-c)\geq3\sqrt[3]{a(-b)(-c)}=3\sqrt[3]{abc}.$$

Comment: Nice proof! There is a little typo $\sqrt{abc},$ the rest is beautiful

Comment: I fixed. Thank you!